# Word for a portion of house for guests

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any specific word for a portion of a house either attached with main building or at the back of the house having one or two rooms specifically for guests?

Comment: Typically these are just called "guest rooms" or "spare rooms".  There is probably a word that would work for this, but it certainly isn't widely used.

Comment: @dotsamuelswan: Yeah, like *guest wing*, or *guest apartment(s)*.

Comment: In the US, if there is a bedroom and bathroom (and possibly other rooms) that are just for guests, these are sometimes called in-law apartments.

Comment: @KitFox: Yes, or [inlaw suite](http://www.bobvila.com/articles/407-adding-an-in-law-suite/pages/1). There are quite a few [variants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_suite#Mother-in-law_apartment), all readily understandable.

Comment: What about annexe? Or 'annexe' is something else?

Comment: A *granny annexe* is a fairly common name in the UK.

Answer (score 4):

A [*guesthouse*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/guesthouse) normally implies a detached structure, which is what I think you mean by "at the back of the house."

A *guest room* would cover this case:

> a bedroom in a home not regularly occupied by a member of the
>   household and kept primarily for guests [M-W]

Comment: And if it is more than one room, it could be a *guest suite* or *guest ensuite*.

Comment: Is 'annexe' a word for this? I have heard few people using it like. We have annexe so you can stay there.

Comment: The word is [_annex_](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=annex); it might also called an _addition_. It tends to imply that the hosts added a room to their house.

Answer (score 4):

***Guest quarters*** would work

I found this definition on a [website](http://www.northfortynews.com/Archive/A200410HHguestQuarters.htm) discussing local zoning laws:

*The current land use code does allow guest quarters, however, meaning the rooms are attached to the family home. The code says, "The single-family character of the structure must be maintained by providing one main entrance to the structure, one set of utility meters and one address for the property."*

Answer (score 0):

My town regulations says,

A single detached **auxiliary habitable unit** may be allowed with living space no more than 800 sq ft.

Answer (score 0):

The word **lodging** might be appropriate, albeit a bit old-fashioned if it is required in a modern context.

> [Definition of LODGING](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lodging) 
> 1) a : a place to live : dwelling 
>      b : lodgment
>   2) a (1) : sleeping accommodations, "found lodging in the barn" (2) : a
>   temporary place to stay, "a lodging for the night" 
>      b : **a room in the house of another used as a residence —usually used in plural**